# getting a next GPS coordinates by adding a fixed distance

Tags: google-maps, gps, coordinates

How to add a fixed distance in meter (13.70 m , 6m ) to current coordinates (lat & long) to get a next coordinates in order to draw a straight line of new 150-250 coordinates points. Is there a formula or equation to do that??
Please support me.

Answer (score 1):

A formula to do this is located at [Lat/lon given radial and distance](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist), but probably the most accurate formula, (most likely more accurate than your instruments can transfer it to a *real world* situation), is [Vincenty's Direct Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae)

There are a number of ways you can work this, both online, and off line, e.g, [Destination given distance & bearing from start point (direct solution)](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html), or [spreadsheet(excel) calculators](http://www.contextures.com/excellatitudelongitude.html)

...but that will get you started.

Here's a fun thing for you to do.  In Python3, install the `pyproj` module. (`sudo pip3 install pyproj`)

```
from pyproj import Geod
geoid = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

def give_me_points(lon, lat, az, dist, number):
    distance = dist
    for point in range(1,number):
        longitude, latitude, return_az = geoid.fwd(lon, lat, az, dist)
        print('#', point,':','Lon:', longitude, 'Lat:',latitude)
        point += 1
        dist = distance * point
```

Call the function

- lon: starting longitude e.g, `2.295050`
- lat: starting latitude `48.857895` (Negative numbers west and south)
- az: azimuth, the direction of your line of points (0-360)
- dist: distance in meters
- number: the number of points you wish to generate (40)

like `give_me_points( 2.295050, 48.857895, 135, 22, 40)`